# How do I copy the protocol link Firefox is trying to open?

Tags: url, firefox, uri

When clicking on a link in Firefox that's a protocol that Firefox can't open, a dialog box appears.

[image: Dialog box that says "Allow this site to open the zoommtg link with zoom.us?]

How do I view or copy the link that it is trying to open, in this case the `zoommtg` link?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming...

Comment: Fair enough, do you think it could get transferred to Super User or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work in Firefox, but opening Chrome's DevTools and going to Network shows the protocol link I was trying to open.